# Facebook like not working for Unauthorized Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fbml

I ma implementing a facebook like function for my site using FBML.If click like as facebook  authorized  its working fine .But Whenever i click as unauthorized it pops up for the login and successfully logs in.But it doesnt perform the like operation. I have to click it again to like it.I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you manually reload a page after log in. It should automatically call like after you login in an authorization popup.